# SIOCADDRT: Сеть недоступна

Tags: route

Пытаюсь выполнить такое задание:
Укажите параметры команды route для настройки маршрута к сети 192.168.5.0 подсеть на 8 адресов
Делаю так:

```
route add -net 192.168.5.0 netmask 255.255.255.248 gw 192.168.5.1
```

Получаю ошибку: `SIOCADDRT: Сеть недоступна`
Что не так?

Вывод `route -n`:

```
route -n
Таблица маршутизации ядра протокола IP
Destination Gateway Genmask Flags Metric Ref Use Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.0.1     0.0.0.0         UG    600    0        0 wlp3s0f0
169.254.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     1000   0        0 wlp3s0f0
192.168.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     600    0        0 wlp3s0f0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Правильная команда:

```
route add -net 192.168.5.0 netmask 255.255.255.248 gw 192.168.0.1
```

Где `gw 192.168.0.1` - Gateway из первой строчки вывода `route`